# In the context of data usage What’s the Difference Between Cloud File Syncing and downloading a file or folder?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, cloud, dropbox, onedrive

In my office computer,I downloaded a file from the Internet and put it on a cloud storage, when I go home and open my laptop it synced with my online storage but if I downloaded the same file directly from the Internet in my both places how much **data I can save or lost in my home network**?

Answer (score 0):

If the file on the internet is static, not going to be modified by the original owner or yourself, it makes no difference if you download it again from internet or from your own cloud storage.

If you need to modify the file yourself, the changes you made will be in your local computers synced with your cloud storage. Then you should be careful not to download the file again from internet to overwrite your own changes.

Comment: Is there any data usage difference between synchronizing and downloading a same file.

Comment: Usually no. Synchronizing is replacing the older file with newer file, same data usage as downloading the newer file.

Comment: Cloud Synchronizing and downloading are using same method to get a new file?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. Which exact Cloud service you are using? Dropbox, OneDrive, or other? Then you should be able to confirm that by contacting Support at Dropbox or Microsoft.

Comment: Dropbox and Google drive